# Angular material: create a divider between mat-tab-labels

Tags: angular, angular-material, tabs, responsive

I have a tab group with three tabs aligned left. I want to add a group of buttons, on the mat tab group, aligned right. I tried using `fxFlex` to create a divider between the tabs and the buttons but it doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know how else I could go about it?

What i have:
[image]

What i want to achieve:
[image]

Code:

```
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start">
  <mat-tab label="Items">Content</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Properties">Content</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Subcategories">Content</mat-tab>

  <!-- <mat-tab disabled fxFlex></mat-tab> Tried to add a disabled tab as a divider here, but it doesnt flex -->

  <mat-tab disabled>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
       <!-- <div fxFlex></div> Tried to add a div with flex here, doesnt work -->
       <!-- Buttons here -->
    </ng-template>

</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Could you share the html?

Comment: @NarenMurali I just edited with a sample of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the below line to the `styles.css` sorry its a bit hackish couldn't find a better solution, just need to forego one `aria-label` with value as spacer.

styles.css

```
div.mat-tab-label[aria-label='spacer'] {
  flex-grow: 1 !important;
}
```

app.com.html

```
<div>
  <span class="example-input-label"> Selected tab index: </span>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="number" [formControl]="selected" />
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div>
  <button
    mat-raised-button
    class="example-add-tab-button"
    (click)="addTab(selectAfterAdding.checked)"
  >
    Add new tab
  </button>
  <mat-checkbox #selectAfterAdding> Select tab after adding </mat-checkbox>
</div>

<mat-tab-group
  [selectedIndex]="selected.value"
  (selectedIndexChange)="selected.setValue($event)"
>
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let index = index" [label]="tab">
    Contents for {{tab}} tab

    <button
      mat-raised-button
      class="example-delete-tab-button"
      [disabled]="tabs.length === 1"
      (click)="removeTab(index)"
    >
      Delete Tab
    </button>
  </mat-tab>

  <mat-tab disabled aria-label="spacer" aria-hidden="true"></mat-tab>

  <mat-tab disabled>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <mat-button-toggle value="bold">Bold</mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle value="italic">Italic</mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle value="underline">Underline</mat-button-toggle>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n2zoh7)